# Open a OpenFileDialog to change the value of a property in a PropertyGrid control?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, propertygrid

In Windows Forms, I'm representing a custom class in a `PropertyGid` control, which has various string properties as you can notice in the next image:

[image]

The problem is that I'm not totally satisfied with the current behavior for changing the value of the string properties. For those properties that expects a file or directory path, like "Target" or "Working Directory" properties, I would like to know if it could be possible and viable to implement a TypeConverter / Type Descriptor that would open a `OpenFileDialog` when clicking in the down arrow at the right of the field in the property grid. That is, to select a file or folder through a `OpenFileDialog`, instead of directly writing the path in the property grid, but still letting the option to directly write the path if I want to do so.

Maybe .NET Framework class library already provides the TypeConverter / TypeDescriptor that I'm requesting?. If not, is this possible to do?. And how to start doing so?.

Or any other idea to be able open a `OpenFileDialog` to change the value of a specific property in a `PropertyGrid` control?.

Comment: The framework doesn't know anything about IShellLink.  Create a modal UITypeEditor to customize value editing.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks for comment. I will start by practicing with the code example at: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor?view=netframework-4.8, but I will remark that those properties are of string data-type.

Comment: Apparently there is a built-in UITypeEditor with class name **FileNameEditor** that could do what I need, or at least that is what is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2373374/1248295. I didn't tried yet.

Comment: That Editor opens the standard file picker dialog (Open File) and lets you choose a file path/name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are builtin [`FileNameEditor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.filenameeditor?view=netframework-4.8) and [`FolderNameEditor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.foldernameeditor?view=netframework-4.8) UI type editors which let you choose file name and folder name, for example:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
public class MyClass
{
    [Editor(typeof(FileNameEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    [Editor(typeof(FolderNameEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string FolderPath { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to customize the `FileNameEditor` to show just txt files, you can override its `InitializeDialog` method:

```
public class MyFileNameEditor : FileNameEditor
{
    protected override void InitializeDialog(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog)
    {
        base.InitializeDialog(openFileDialog);
        openFileDialog.Filter = "text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my application, I have a property that takes a icon file path, another property that can take a file or folder, and other property that takes a folder path.

So, I had to write variations for each one of these properties...

The easiest one, and in case of you are satisfied with the `FolderBrowserDialog` appearance and limitations, then is to directly specify the `System.Windows.Forms.Design.FolderNameEditor` class in the `EditorAttribute` class. Otherwise, **Ooki.Dialogs** is a good open-source library as an alternative to get a modern-look dialog.

The second easiest one is the editor for selecting a icon file path:

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Provides a user interface for selecting a icon file name.
''' </summary>
''' <seealso cref="FileNameEditor"/>
Friend Class IconFileNameEditor : Inherits FileNameEditor

#Region " Constructors "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="IconFileNameEditor"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Private Methods "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes the open file dialog when it is created.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="ofd">
    ''' The <see cref="OpenFileDialog"/> to use to select a file name.
    ''' </param>
    Protected Overrides Sub InitializeDialog(ByVal dlg As OpenFileDialog)
        MyBase.InitializeDialog(dlg)

        With dlg
            .Multiselect = False
            .RestoreDirectory = True
            .DereferenceLinks = True
            .Filter = "Icon Files (*.ico;*.icl;*.exe;*.dll)|*.ico;*.icl;*.exe;*.dll|Icons|*.ico|Libraries|*.dll|Programs|*.exe"
            .FilterIndex = 1
            .SupportMultiDottedExtensions = True
        End With
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

For selecting a file path or folder path, and in search of something already done and open-source in order to avoid adding external dependancies to my project, I took a custom `FileFolderDialog` class  provided in [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44914/Select-file-or-folder-from-the-same-dialog) article, and I managed to write the editor like this:

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Provides a user interface for selecting a file or folder name.
''' </summary>
''' <seealso cref="UITypeEditor"/>
Public Class FileOrFolderNameEditor : Inherits UITypeEditor

#Region " Constructors "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="FileOrFolderNameEditor"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Public Methods"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the editor style used by the <see cref="UITypeEditor.EditValue(IServiceProvider, Object)"/> method.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="context">
    ''' An <see cref="ITypeDescriptorContext"/> that can be used to gain additional context information.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <returns>
    ''' A <see cref="UITypeEditorEditStyle"/> value that indicates the style of editor used 
    ''' by the <see cref="UITypeEditor.EditValue(IServiceProvider, Object)"/> method. 
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' If the <see cref="UITypeEditor"/> does not support this method, 
    ''' then <see cref="UITypeEditor.GetEditStyle"/> will return <see cref="UITypeEditorEditStyle.None"/>.
    ''' </returns>
    Public Overrides Function GetEditStyle(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As UITypeEditorEditStyle
        Return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Edits the specified object's value using the editor style indicated by the <see cref="UITypeEditor.GetEditStyle"/> method.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="context">
    ''' An <see cref="ITypeDescriptorContext"/> that can be used to gain additional context information.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="provider">
    ''' An <see cref="IServiceProvider"/> that this editor can use to obtain services.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="value">
    ''' The object to edit.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <returns>
    ''' The new value of the object. 
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' If the value of the object has not changed, this should return the same object it was passed.
    ''' </returns>
    Public Overrides Function EditValue(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext, ByVal provider As IServiceProvider, ByVal value As Object) As Object

        Using dlg As New OpenFileOrFolderDialog()
            If (dlg.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK) Then
                Return dlg.SelectedPath
            End If
        End Using

        Return MyBase.EditValue(context, provider, value)

    End Function

#End Region

End Class
```

It was pretty easy at all.